# Отправка письма с вложением

Tags: битрикс, события, отправка

Пытаюсь отправить из Битрикса письмо по событию. Контент письма - содержимое инфоблока. Отправка производится так:

```
$obEvent = new CEvent;
                $obEvent->Send('QUESTION_FORM_ADDED', SITE_ID, $eventFields);
```

То есть указывается шаблон, ид сайта, массив полей письма. Письма уходят нормально.
$eventFields - массив полей.
В документации Битрикса указано, что можно отправить и файлы, указав из абсолютные пути в массиве:

```
CEvent::Send(
 string event,
 mixed lid,
 array fields,
 string duplicate="Y",
 int message_id="",
 array **files**
)
```

Подозреваю, что отправлять нужно как-то так:

```
 $obEvent = new CEvent;
                    $obEvent->Send('QUESTION_FORM_ADDED', SITE_ID, $eventFields, $FILES);
```

Так вот как получить массив ($FILES) этих путей из элемента инфоблока?
Есть у кого опыт отправки файлов таким образом?
Инфоблок - форма обратной связи, каждое письмо - элемент инфоблока. В элементах файлы сохраняются нормально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

чтобы отправить файлы их надо сохранить и получить ID
примерно так:

```
$files=array();
foreach ($_FILES as $file){
    if (!empty($file['tmp_name']) {
         $files[]=CFile::SaveFile($file);
    }
}

CEvent::Send('QUESTION_FORM_ADDED', SITE_ID, $eventFields, 'Y','',$files);
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, это в том случае, если мы пытаемся отправить письмо перед сохранением элемента инфоблока?
Просто у нас изначально есть уже сохраненные файлы как свойства элемента инфоблока. Вопрос в том, как их упаковать в массив?

Comment: если есть сохранненые файлы уже в элеиенте, то битрикс хранит их ID  нужно подставить массив ID  вместо $files

Answer (score 1):

Все просто - сохраняем файл,

```
$fileId = CFile::SaveFile(
                  array(
                    "name" => $arUpdateValues['PREVIEW_PICTURE']['name'],           // имя файла, как оно будет в письме
                    "size" => $arUpdateValues['PREVIEW_PICTURE']['size'],   // работает и без указания размера
                    "tmp_name" => $filePath,            // собственно файл
                    // "type" => "",                    // тип, не ясно зачем
                    "old_file" => "0",                  // ID "старого" файла
                    "del" => "N",                       // удалять прошлый?
                    "MODULE_ID" => "",                  // имя модуля, работает и так
                    "description" => "",                // описание
                    // "content" => "содержимое файла"  // если указать, то вместо файла будет указанный текст
                  ),
                  'mails',  // относительный путь от upload, где будут храниться файлы
                  false,    // ForceMD5
                  false     // SkipExt
                );
```

прикрепляем, потом удаляем его.

```
CEvent::SendImmediate(
                   'YF_REVEW', 
                   's1', 
                   $arFields, 
                   $Duplicate = "N",
                   '',
                   [$fileId]
               );
```

подробнее здесь
[http://phpjs.ru/2017/06/16/битрикс-отправка-письма-с-вложением-с/](http://phpjs.ru/2017/06/16/%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81/)